# Hyper-V: allow communication between two internal NAT networks

Tags: networking, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012, hyper-v-server-2016

I am a bit new to networking in Hyper-V, and I am not sure how to connect two separate NAT networks to each other.

I used the following link to create two internal NAT networks:
https://www.petri.com/using-nat-virtual-switch-hyper-v

Here are the specifications of the internal networks:

Admin:

- Network: 10.0.0.0/20
- Hyper-V internal vNIC IP: 10.0.0.1

DMZ:

- Network: 10.1.0.0/20
- Hyper-V internal vNIC IP: 10.1.0.1

The connection for both is shared with the external IP address of Hyper-V server: 192.168.137.17, and then is forwarded to a router on 192.168.137.1

My question is, how can I allow the DMZ and Admin networks to talk to each other? As of right now, they both have no problems reaching the outside world, e.g. 8.8.8.8. Is there is a way to let two NetIPAddresses talk to each other?

Following is a Paste Bin of Hyper-V's [Get-VMSwitch](https://pastebin.com/jdhBntX3), [Get-NetIPAddress](https://pastebin.com/PupvbS56), and [Get-NetNAT](https://pastebin.com/J8R97TS1)

Answer (score 2):

Each network is effectively isolated behind a separate NAT router managed by Hyper-V, in a similar way that your home router isolates your home network behind a single public IP address. This is how the networks are accessing the outside world.

The challenge is to connect the two separate networks together within the Hyper-V world and this will need a router. It would be a simple matter to create a virtual router and connect it to both networks using two virtual NICs.

Create a VM and provide it with two NICS - one in each network. Assign it an IP in each network and install an OS that will allow you to route between the two networks. Here are some examples:

- Simple Ubuntu VM: https://jchornsey.wordpress.com/2018/02/12/creating-a-very-basic-router-for-a-hyper-v-private-network-part-two-creating-the-router/
- Simple pfSense VM: https://www.dtonias.com/install-pfsense-router-hyper-v-server/
- Simple Windows Server VM: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/canberrapfe/2013/04/22/routing-traffic-between-subnets-in-your-hyper-v-lab/

Comment: I thought that hyper-v might have some internal routing that could do it. But this will work too, thanks!

Comment: It may do, but I am not aware of it. Someone else may suggest how it can be done natively.